# pointer remapping issues trying to print matrix's diagonal?

Tags: pointers, fortran

I tried to print the diagonal of a matrix using pointer remapping in fortran. But i received an error. Any idea how to solve it? This is the program

```
program try

    implicit none

    integer , dimension (3,3), target :: a
    a=reshape([1, 2, 3,4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[3,3])

    real, pointer, dimension(:, :) :: matrix
    real, pointer, dimension(:) :: diagonal, base
    allocate (base(3*3))

    matrix(1:3, 1:3) => base
    diagonal => base(1:9:4)

    print *, diagonal

end program try
```

I got this error:

```
unexpected data declaration statement. at line 9 and 10
```

(where i declare the pointers)

Comment: The remapping is an executable statement, it cannot be between the data declaration statements.

Comment: You can't declare variables after code. So the pointer declaration lines need to be before the line `a = reshape...`.

Comment: Ok thank u,  now i have modified the code in this: program try

    implicit none
    integer , dimension (3,3), target :: a
    integer, dimension(:, :), pointer :: matrix
    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: diagonal, base

    allocate (base(3*3))
    matrix(1:3, 1:3) => base
    diagonal => base(1:9:4)

    matrix => a

    a=reshape([1, 2, 3,4 ,5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[3,3]) 
    print *, diagonal

end program try
 but i get this: 
    17397152  1735357008  1701602145. Why i get these numbers?

Comment: @DomenicoBianchi please ask a new question rather than asking questions in comments; with no newlines that code is quite hard to read.

Comment: i did it now. i couldn t do it before cause i have to wait 1.5 hours beetween the questions, thanks